# CMD does and doesn't see this file?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm having a lot of problems with a particular file, `LockupSystem.MDB` . It doesn't help that there are lots of files with similar names.

I tried to `dir` to find the file but I couldn't find it. After a while I tried piping it through `find` with no better luck before trying `dir` for the file directly.

Here's what's happening: `dir` for the file directly? No problem! DIR all files? Doesn't show up!

[image: Screenshot]

1. What's happening here?
2. Is there a problem with this file? I think my program is saying either this file doesn't exist or it can't access it.

Comment: barlop's answer sounds likely to be the case. The file is hidden. What bothers me is your second point -- what is the error your program is returning? Assuming the file is actually hidden, your application should still be able to read the file. Hidden just means it won't return in a directory listing (or in Windows Explorer). Maybe the file is not in that directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Find is a case-sensitive search

`lockupsystem` (the actual basename of the file as *you can see* reported by the `dir` command) is not the same as `LockupSystem` (what you asked `find` to scan for).

Nothing is saying that the file doesn't exist.  Nor is there any mystery with `hidden` attributes and whatnot.  (The first `dir` command in the question wouldn't have shown the file in the first place if that had been the case.)  It's very simple: You didn't spell your command-line correctly.

Spell the name of what you are looking for correctly in the `find` command.  Or use `find`'s case-insensitivity option.

Comment: Yup; add the `/i` switch to the `find` command and it should work.